# Inside Windows 10 Sandbox

Tags: windows-10, sandbox

Windows 10 is scheduled to push 1903 edition which has built in sand box feature. Where can we find some deep tech inside of the feature? For example, can we play video games at almost native performance in the sand box?

Updated:I just tried Windows sandbox. Slow speed (maybe due to lazy start,etc), really no state save (totally insane). Feel that it is not useful at all. If you need to try out an App some time, try it in VMWare is not that bad and you can save states and continue to try it later and there is not that many Apps to try out so even VMWare is slow it doesn't matter. Just remove the feature.

Comment: Warning: This may not be what you want for games : "When you’re done experimenting, you can simply close the Windows Sandbox application. All sandbox content will be discarded and permanently deleted".

Comment: @harrymc I also noticed this. But I think it's not possible there is no way to save the state and use the sand box as a VM, if so, I can only say that MS is crazy...

Comment: Have any idea why I get down voted for this question?

Comment: Most probably because the subject is games. I suggest looking into alternatives like [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/).

Comment: @harrymc The reason to use MS tech is to get rid of malware. Open source is best. For non-open source, my theory is the bigger and the richer the company is, the lesser possibility it contains malware.

Comment: Sandboxie is well-known and has kept my computer clean even when testing doubtful software. (Their website seems to be down at the moment.)

Comment: The purpose of the sandbox in Windows is different than your needs and preferences. To make the leap from this to saying it's about money or poor decisions on MS' part is silly, a non sequitur. Microsoft already has a very capable hypervisor included in Windows that would work as well as anything else for more intensive tasks, so why would they make something else like that? This is probably one reason why you're getting downvotes.

Comment: @ music2myear  If hypervisor is enough, then what is Docker for? Docker/Windows 10 Sandbox is all about light weight----less disk/CPU resource usage and faster startup. According to MS, Sandbox is to test Apps, I said it is useless because VMs can already satisfy this need. What is useful is a light weight Windows container under Windows which can save states and so is better than VMs in most aspects.

Comment: You can do snapshot and clone in Win 10. v2004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Kernel-Internals/Windows-Sandbox/ba-p/301849) from Microsoft has details of Windows Sandbox announcement. In the Graphics Virtualization section of the post, it explains how graphics will be handled and later in the section states that:

> This enables the Windows Sandbox VM to benefit from hardware accelerated rendering, with Windows dynamically allocating graphics resources where they are needed across the host and guest. The result is improved performance and responsiveness for apps running in Windows Sandbox, as well as improved battery life for graphics-heavy use cases.
>
> To take advantage of these benefits, you’ll need a system with a compatible GPU and graphics drivers (WDDM 2.5 or newer). Incompatible systems will render apps in Windows Sandbox with Microsoft’s CPU-based rendering technology.

I guess if you have latest drivers with a compatible GPU, the performance when playing games in the sandbox should be closed to or similar to when playing outside of it.